# React image and video player with given duration

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I want to have simple media player(image and video) that automatically starts displaying image or play video given in JSON file.
My code is:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'

import './App.css'

type MyProps = {}
type MyState = {currentImage: number; type: string[]; duration: number[]; url: string[]}
export class App extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
        this.switchImage = this.switchImage.bind(this)
        this.state = {currentImage: 0, type: [], duration: [], url: []}
    }

    async getSource() {
        let durationArray: number[] = []
        let urlArray: string[] = []
        let typeArray: string[] = []
        let sources = [
            {
                name: 'Person 1',
                type: 'image',
                url: 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240/cat',
                duration: 5,
            },
            {
                name: 'Person 2',
                type: 'image',
                url: 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog',
                duration: 3,
            },
            {
                name: 'Video 1',
                type: 'video',
                url: 'https://file-examples.com/storage/fe07f859fd624073f9dbdc6/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4',
                duration: 7,
            },
        ]

        sources.forEach((source: {url: string; type: string; duration: number}) => {
            urlArray.push(source.url)
            typeArray.push(source.type)
            durationArray.push(source.duration)
        })
        this.setState({url: urlArray, duration: durationArray, type: typeArray})
    }

    switchImage() {
        if (this.state.currentImage < this.state.url.length - 1) {
            this.setState({currentImage: this.state.currentImage + 1})
        } else {
            this.setState({currentImage: 0})
        }
        return this.state.currentImage
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getSource()
        setInterval(this.switchImage, 5000)
    }

    render() {
        const sourceType = this.state.type[this.state.currentImage]
        console.log(sourceType)
        return (
            <div className="player">
                {sourceType === 'image' ? (
                    <img src={this.state.url[this.state.currentImage]} width="auto" height="auto" />
                ) : (
                    <video autoPlay src={this.state.url[this.state.currentImage]} width="auto" height="auto"></video>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

From the JSON sources I get *url* , *duration* and *type* of each source and play the image or video with the given duration.

1: Is it possible to play each image with the given duration and then make next.

2: Should I convert this to a function component? or maybe move the whole code into a new component?

Answer (score 0):

I have kind of modified a few things on your app.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sources: undefined,
      currentImage: -1
    };
  }

  getSource = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let sources = [
        {
          name: "Person 1",
          type: "image",
          url: "https://loremflickr.com/320/240/cat",
          duration: 5
        },
        {
          name: "Person 2",
          type: "image",
          url: "https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog",
          duration: 3
        },
        {
          name: "Video 1",
          type: "video",
          url:
            "https://file-examples.com/storage/fe07f859fd624073f9dbdc6/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4",
          duration: 7
        }
      ];
      resolve(sources);
    });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    let mySources = await this.getSource();
    console.log("mySources", mySources);
    this.setState(
      {
        sources: mySources,
        currentImage: 0
      },
      () => {
        this.displayNext(mySources[0].duration * 1000);
      }
    );
  }

  displayNext = (time) => {
    console.log(this.state.currentImage);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(
        {
          currentImage:
            this.state.currentImage == this.state.sources.length - 1
              ? 0
              : this.state.currentImage + 1
        },
        () => {
          this.displayNext(
            this.state.sources[this.state.currentImage].duration * 1000
          );
        }
      );
    }, time);
  };

  render() {
    const _sources = this.state.sources;
    const _index = this.state.currentImage;
    return _sources && _index >= 0 ? (
      <div className="player">
        {_sources[_index].type === "image" ? (
          <img src={_sources[_index].url} width="auto" height="auto" />
        ) : (
          <video
            autoPlay
            src={_sources[_index].url}
            width="auto"
            height="auto"
          ></video>
        )}
      </div>
    ) : (
      <></>
    );
  }
}
```

Explaination:

So instead of using setInterval use setTimeout.
Trigger the first timeout to be invoked 'x' seconds after the first image starts to display. This value of 'x' seconds will be the value of duration you want to display the image.
Next to make it recursive, as soon as the timeout invokes, change the state and set the next timeout!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a implementation in **Vue** typescript:

```
<template>
  <img :src="currentImgSrc">
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, onMounted, reactive, nextTick, withDefaults, defineProps } from 'vue';

type Image = string;
type Images = Array<Image>;

interface Props {
  images: Images;
  duration?: number; // in seconds
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  duration: 1,
});

const state = reactive<{
  imageElements: Array<HTMLImageElement>;
  currentImageIndex: number;
  numberOfLoadedImages: number;
  error: string;
}>({
  imageElements: [],
  currentImageIndex: -1,
  numberOfLoadedImages: 0,
  error: '',
});

const currentImgSrc = computed(() => {
  if (state.error) {
    return '';
  } else {
    return state.imageElements[state.currentImageIndex]?.src || '';
  }
});

const fetchImagesAndTriggerPlayback = async () => {
  props.images.forEach((_, index) => {
    const image = new Image();

    image.src = props.images[index];

    image.onload = async () => {
      state.numberOfLoadedImages++;

      await nextTick();

      if (state.numberOfLoadedImages === props.images.length) {
        showNextImage(); // Trigger playback
      }
    };

    image.onerror = () => {
      state.error = 'Something went wrong';
    };

    state.imageElements = [...state.imageElements, image];
  });
};

const showNextImage = () => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    state.currentImageIndex =
      state.currentImageIndex === state.imageElements.length - 1 ? 0 : state.currentImageIndex + 1;

    await nextTick();

    showNextImage();
  }, props.duration * 1000);
};

onMounted(() => {
  fetchImagesAndTriggerPlayback();
});
</script>
```